# Django: model not defined?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I can't use the model I defined in Django.

My model is defined inside `my_object/models.py`:

```py
class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name")
```

If I launch `shell_plus`, I can't use my model:

```py
# ./manage.py shell_plus
# Shell Plus Model Imports
...
from my_object.models import MyObject
...

In [1]: MyObject                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-05203d19fbcd> in <module>
----> 1 MyObject

NameError: name 'MyObject' is not defined
```

My config: Python 3.6, Django 1.11.

---

EDIT: I don't have the following problem anymore, it was caused by a legitimate fail, the query does not have any results:

> And I cannot launch tests either, I get this error:
>   `my_object.models.DoesNotExist: MyObject matching query does not
>   exist.`

Comment: is your model inside any directory/package rather than app directory?

Comment: have `__init__.py` above my_object directory

Comment: @ShafikurRahman: my model is defined directly in the app, inside `my_object/models.py`.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari: I already have an empty `__init__.py` above `my_object`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Django Shell (`./manage.py shell`)?

Comment: @JPG: Yes I have the same behaviour.

Comment: The error is not caused by this code. Somewhere you have a query at module or class level that is trying to find an object in the db before it is defined. Show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the origin of this behaviour, and `ipdb` seems to be the culprit.

Removing the `import ipdb` line inside one of my Python files solved my problem, I don't really know why.